# fopen() file path in C

Tags: c, fopen, relative-path, file-handling

I have clone a git repository in C:/Repo. I am trying to open a file which lies in the git at some location ,for example, git/program/slm/error.txt. I am using fopen() API in C language to open the file and the filepath I am specifying is "C:/Repo/git/program/slm/error.txt". The program seems to be working while providing the above mentioned path. But,I want to make this program generic so that it can work on other systems as well as in other systems it is not necessary that the git will be cloned in C:/Repo only,this is local to my system. git/program/slm/error.txt is the relative path and will be common for all the system.

Can anyone please help me how what filepathname should I provide to make it generic so that it works on all the systems?

Answer (score 1):

Take your repository path as commandline argument and then when you want to access the file append the repository path and the relative path that you want to access.